# How to increment variable value by 5 iterations with multiple conditions

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to put some pieces of code into the loop. What I want to achieve is add the tax to total by every 5 product quantity added.

```
if($items['qty'] >= 5 && $items['qty'] < 10){
    $tax += $items[$type] * 1;
}

if($items['qty'] >= 10 && $items['qty'] < 15){
    $tax += $items[$type] * 2;
}

if($items['qty'] >= 15 && $items['qty'] < 20){
    $tax += $items[$type] * 3;
}
if($items['qty'] >= 20 && $items['qty'] < 25){
    $tax += $items[$type] * 4;
}
```

I tried this code, it works with a static value. It would be great if someone helps me to put this code into the loop.

**Example:** tax = $10. For product quantity 1 to 4 the tax will be $10. For product quantity 5 to 9 the tax will be $20, for product quantity 9 to 14 the tax will be $30 so on...

Comment: I am sorry, i forgot to mention what is $items[$type] here. So let me tell you $items[$type] is nothing but the tax itself which is coming from the product table. Means $items[$type] = 10;

Answer (score 0):

$items['data'] = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15);

$tax = 10;

$j = 5;

$k = 1;
for($i=0;$i < $j;$i++){

```
echo $items['data'][$i];
```

}
$j = $j+5;

echo    "
".$tax*$k ."
";

$k= $k+1;

for($i=5;$i < $j;$i++){

```
echo $items['data'][$i];
```

}
$j = $j+5;

echo    "
".$tax*$k ."
";

$k= $k+1;

for($i=10;$i < $j; $i++){

```
echo $items['data'][$i];
```

}

$j = $j+5;

echo    "
".$tax*$k ."
";

$k= $k+1;

Comment: Please check the formatting of your code.  Also may be worth adding some description of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should help in calculating the factor. What is $type here?

```
$items['qty'] = 24;
$tax = 10;
$floorFactor = floor($items['qty'] / 5);

$factor = $floorFactor === 0 ? 1 : $floorFactor;

echo '$floorFactor is ' . floor($items['qty'] / 5);

$tax += $items['qty'] * $factor;

echo "<br > tax is $tax <br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it and you might not need a loop (3 line of code might be enought), but you want a loop you might try something like this. It's a loop as you asked:

$j increment 1 by one in numerical order, so each time it will be a multiple of 5 it will increase the multiplicator by 10 (your tax) up to the value in $items['qty'].

$multiplicator is equal to 10 at the start then it will increase by 10 in the the loop for each 5 items, for the maintenance if you change the tax value you only change this one.

($j % 5) === 0) is to check if $j is a multiple of 5, same here for the maintenance you will need to change the multiple if you decide you want more or less items to change the tax.

```
    $multiplicator = 10; 
             for($j = 1; $j <= $items['qty']; $j++){ 
                     if(($j % 5) === 0){ 
                         $multiplicator += 10;
                         }
                     //echo $j."-".$multiplicator."<br>"; // to check how it works
                     }
//$tax += $items[$type] + $multiplicator; // I would finish like that but i don't know what is $type
// so to match your multiplication number in $tax += $items[$type] * x you need the code below as well
//(($multiplicator/10)-1) is to match your multiplication numbers in your code as $tax += $items[$type] * x;
        if((($multiplicator/10)-1) == 0){ 
            $tax += $items[$type]; // less than 5 items
            }
        else{
            $tax += $items[$type] * (($multiplicator/10)-1); // 5 items and above 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I achieved this using array functions and foreach loop. This may be a long code but i could not achieve it quickly.

```
            if ($items['qty'] >= 5){
                  $tax += $items[$type];   // $items[$type] is a tax that is being fetched from the product table
                  // Calculation Start
                  $keys = range(1, 25);
                  $num = range($items['qty'], $items['qty'] + 5);
                  $a = array_fill_keys($keys, $num);

                  foreach ($a as $keys => $endnum) {
                        if ($endnum[$keys] % 5 == 0) {
                            if($items['qty'] >= $items['qty'] && $items['qty'] < $endnum[$keys]){
                                $range = range(5, 10000, 5);
                                $count = array_search($endnum[$keys], $range);
                                $tax += $items[$type] * $count; 
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                  }
                  // Calculation Ends
            }else{
                $tax += $items[$type];
            }
```